# Spark error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 when trying to explode date sequence

Tags: apache-spark

I have written this code on Spark 2.4.0 using PySpark:

```py
grouped_df = spark.read.parquet('min_max_date')
# We create new dataframe with whole interval of months for every client to join it with the original
missing_dates = (grouped_df
    .select("SK_APPLICATION",
            explode(sequence(col("min_date"), col("max_date"), expr("interval 1 month"))).alias("DATE"))
    .withColumn("CODE", lit("#"))
                )
missing_dates.write.mode('overwrite').parquet('missing_dates')
```

This code tries to create rows with separate months in interval between min and max date, but there is some problem with explode function. Here is log:

```
Lost task 1.0 in stage 43.0 (TID 654, os-4894.homecredit.ru, executor 24): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1408)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:413)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

group_df contents look like:

```
+------------------+------------+------------+
|SK_APPLICATION    |  MIN_DATE  |   MAX_DATE |
|__________________|____________|____________|
|  2343255         | 01-01-2005 | 05-05-2010 |
|__________________|____________|____________|
| 12334234         | 01-05-2007 | 01-10-2015 |
+------------------+------------+------------+
```

SK_APPLICATION has decimal type, MIN_DATE, MAX_DATE are DateType

At the same time calling just `missing_dates.show()` works correctly. Any idea, what's the problem?

Comment: Could you provide us a sample df, like the result of `grouped_df` to see what it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the reason, why this code doesn't work. However, I understood that the problem was in explode function and I found the alternative solution. The problem was solved after I changed sequence into array. The working version looks like this:

```
grouped_df = spark.read.parquet('min_max_date')

def get_dates(start_date, end_date):
    dates = []
    date = start_date.replace(day=1)
    while date <= end_date:
        dates.append(date)
        if date.month == 12:
            date = date.replace(year=date.year+1, month=1)
        else:
            date = date.replace(month=date.month+1)
    return dates

get_dates_udf = udf(get_dates, ArrayType(DateType()))

grouped_df_with_dates = grouped_df.withColumn("dates", get_dates_udf("min_date", "max_date"))

grouped_df_exploded = grouped_df_with_dates.select("SK_APPLICATION", explode("dates").alias("DATE"), lit("#").alias("CODE"))

grouped_df_exploded.write.mode('overwrite').parquet('missing_dates')
```

However, my code works if you use Spark 3.3.4. So if you have this problem and you are able to update Spark, it will be the easiest way to fix this error.